# In Firebase I need to extract data based on 2 tables

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase I need to extract data from tables/nodes.

I have one table called **jobs** and another called **organisations**.

**Outcome required:** I need to get all companies that don't have any jobs.

**This is a dummy example of my list of jobs node/table (note this is almost a replica):**

```
jobs: {
    -k3resdfsfsdfsdf:{jobName: test1, companyId: 1h3hr4jrkfk5k5kff},
    -k3resdfsfsdfsdf:{jobName: test2, companyId: 2h3hr4jrkfk5k5kff},
    -k3resdfsfsdfsdf:{jobName: test3, companyId: 2h3hr4jrkfk5k5kff}    
}
```

**This is my organisations table (note this is almost a replica):**

```
organisations: {
    fsdfsddfsfsdfsdf:{companyId: 1h3hr4jrkfk5k5kff, companyName: comp a, address: 12 road},
    jhhjresdfsfsdfsf:{companyId: 2h3hr4jrkfk5k5kff, companyName: comp b, address: 11 road},
    hsdfskhjfsdfsdf: {companyId: 3h3hr4jrkfk5k5kff, companyName: comp c, address: 10 road}    
}
```

I want to get all organisations who dont have a job in the jobs list
I basically want to cross reference.

**This is my attempt:**

```
    this.firebaseBaseUrl = "hiddenForStackOverflow";

    this.refOrg = new Firebase(firebaseBaseUrl + "/organisations");
    this.refJobs = new Firebase(firebaseBaseUrl + "/jobs");

    this.refOrg .once('value', function(snapshot: any) {

            snapshot.forEach(function(orgSnapshot: any) {

                var listOfOrganisations= orgSnapshot.val();

                // Not sure how to do this without looping through both lists, which could be very slow.

            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a child node to the organizations node that ties it to the jobs

```
organizations
   -company0
     companyName:
     address:
     jobs:
       k3resdfsfsdfsdf: true
       k8jsmnima90djis: true
   -company1
     companyName:
     address:
   -company2
     companyName:
     address:
     jobs:
       k989ijikakmsks: true
```

then you can query for the organizations where the jobs node doesn't exist. This Swift 3 code snippet will return company1 only:

```
orgRef.queryOrdered(byChild:"jobs").queryEqual(toValue: nil)
      .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
             print(snapshot)      
});
```

OR

Just keep an open_job_count: node in each company node and if there are no jobs open it will be 0. Then query for open_job_count: 0

Comment: I can't add any new fields. Reason is I have a lot of data already that I need to query as above

Comment: @AngularM Well, then unfortunately you will have lot of looping to do and reading in a lot of data to loop through it.